# expanded mnist dataset in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I just need to train the network with the MNIST dataset with expanded and displaced training images and expanded but not displaced training images and compared the two results.And explain why the translation allowed the network to learn more (or possibly the same)

for this question I have used the code from MNIST dataset... but it keeps running for the whole day without showing an output...

```
C:\Users\malin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\signal\pool.py:574: 
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional 
indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. 
In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, 
which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

Above is the message that is running in mylaptop for one day ... I don't know how to answer this question without seeing any output

```
import network3
from network3 import Network
from network3 import ConvPoolLayer, FullyConnectedLayer, SoftmaxLayer
from network3 import ReLU
#%%
mini_batch_size = 10
expanded_training_data,validation_data, test_data  = network3.load_data_shared(
        "mnist_expanded.pkl.gz")
#%%
net = Network([
        ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 1, 28, 28), 
                      filter_shape=(20, 1, 5, 5), 
                      poolsize=(2, 2), 
                      activation_fn=ReLU),
        ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 20, 12, 12), 
                      filter_shape=(40, 20, 5, 5), 
                      poolsize=(2, 2), 
                      activation_fn=ReLU),
        FullyConnectedLayer(n_in=40*4*4, n_out=100, activation_fn=ReLU),
        SoftmaxLayer(n_in=100, n_out=10)], mini_batch_size)
net.SGD(expanded_training_data, 60, mini_batch_size, 0.03, 
            validation_data, test_data, lmbda=0.1)
```

Comment: on [Google Colabs](https://colab.research.google.com/) you can use for free powerfull computers with GPU or even TPU (chip for Neural Networks)

Comment: this message is only warning and probably you could even forget it. It seems you have some data in list, array or something similar which can be changed accidently and it suggests to convert it to tuples which can't be changed accidently.